# How can I create a controllable solenoid array?

Tags: transistors, diodes, multiplexer, solenoid

So to briefly summarize my situation, I am trying to create a programmable solenoid array that will be used to raise and lower pins for a braille display. Considering that each braille character has 6 dots and that I want to be able to output 5 characters, I will need to control at least 30 solenoids. 
I've attached an idea that I had on how to tackle this problem, however, I am unsure how feasible it is or if there are some other things that I should consider. The design would work so that one character would be updated at a time. Any advice or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do the solenoids need to remain powered to hold the pins up?

Comment: What are some of your other design criteria? How will the characters be programmed and through what interface? An Arduino Mega, for instance, can easily drive 30 independent digital outputs at the same time. All you would need is a drive circuit between the solenoid and Arduino.

Comment: @PeterBennett although not explicitly stated, I'd assume: yes.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: I assumed so, too.  He'll need something much more complicated than his sketch indicates...

Comment: @PeterBennett well, a micrcontroller with 30 outputs of four 8-bit shift registers and an arbitrary SPI source... not really all that complicated to implement something better than proposed.

Comment: See https://www.collaborizm.com/project/B16Qw9mO for a project that's already on the go. From what I've read before, Braille works when there is relative motion between the finger and the dots. In other words, resting a finger on a single six-dot character and having it change does not result in a good user experience. Either the finger needs to move or the dots need to scroll.

Comment: Hey susjam, it's been 5 days, and you've not reacted to anything we wrote. How about an acceptance / upvote /downvote of the answer, or a comment? It feels a bit mean to ask something and then not giving any feedback to the answerers.

Comment: Hey Marcus, that was not my intention at all and I'm sorry it came across that way. I actually upvoted your comments as well as some others in the thread, however, my account is still too new for the votes to show up. I didn't realize there was an acceptance system, however, both of the answers that I received are options that I am currently looking into. Thank you again for your time and patience and apologies for leaving everyone in the dark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like "updating" is not the only problem here: you'd want your solenoids to stay energized the whole time, until the next character replaces the old one in the same position.

"How do I control a lot of loads" is a problem that one either tackles by:

- Using a microcontroller with a sufficient number of outputs – at 30, that's not really a rare requirement, at all;
- Using some simple serial-to-parallel IO extender.

The last is very classically done with latched, serial-in, parallel-out *shift register* (that's a term you should definitely google!). These have just three inputs:

1. "clock", which goes high when the value (high/low) of the data pin should be shifted in,
2. "data", which is the value getting shifted in, and
3. "latch", which is used to tell the component that it should now update all its outputs based on the values stored in the shift register.

As outputs, it would have

- the actual outputs that get controlled as described above
- a data out, which takes the value of last entry of the shift register, as it gets "shifted out"
- often, a buffered version of "clock" and "latch" as described above.

That way, you can daisy-chain as many shift registers as you like (for example, ten 8-bit shift registers, yielding control for 80 pins in total).

The interface is really simple; most microcontrollers implement it under the name "SPI", but you could even "bitbang" it with a switch for data and two pushbuttons for clock and latch, if you want to explore how things work.

Answer (score -1):

I first try to write something on the schematics you have posted.

Starting with the right schematic. That's basically correct if you add something on the right side of the solenoids. You did not indicate any ground or opposite voltage by adding an appropriate symbol. But considering the rest of your drawings I think you had that in mind. \$V_a/$ must be a positive voltage to make that circuit work whatever switch (the symbol represents a mechanical switch) you are using. That's because the diodes have to be reversed during normal operation or they will produce a short circuit. They have to be reversed.

I get the impression, you want to build some kind of matrix with row and column control, where the one is addressing the character and the other is addressing the pin within the character, am I right? Unfortunately it is not very clear from the drawings, so I had to guess.

The left schematic shows some basic understanding of the use of transistors as switches. However, the polarity is going to be problematic here. You drew NPN-tranistors, which, given you intend to use them in the omnipresent emmiter-circuit, need a negative potential on the emitter and a positive on the collector and the base to switch on. If you apply a positive voltage to the right end of the solenoids, again, the diodes will produce a short circuit.

To reduce the problem to the principle I assumed 2 characters with only two pins and added a schematic which demonstrates the row/column system, if you want to implement it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9XFf5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Please ignore the values in the schematic, they aren't calculated.
You may notice the resistors. They are necessary to limit the base current.

The signals beginning with "Char" activate the individual characters and the signals beginning with "Pin" activate the pin. This method however brings up some limitations. You can activate the same symbols on all characters at the same time, but you cannot display different symbols simultaneously. To perform that, you have to switch very fast between the characters, which might be complicated.

Comment: Uh, very fastly switching solenoids? Would be a shame if someone was building an inverting SMPS in your braille display...

Comment: The solenoids can keep their current :) Should add some filtering caps.